# Number format column with pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()?

Tags: pandas, pandasql

I've a process than reads the information from a Microsoft SQL database using:

```
df = psql.read_sql(sql, con=connection)
print(df)
```

This function is used in many processes so variable `sql` doesn't have the same columns (variable structure).

Then I get, for example, the following data:

```
STORE EMAIL_CONTACT VALUE
10    a@mail.com    2.2100
23    b@mail.com    0.7990
```

Everything is fine to this point.

When extracting to csv using:

```
file = r"Test.csv"
df.to_csv(file, sep=";", index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

The output is the following:

```
"STORE";"EMAIL_CONTACT";"VALUE"
"10.0";"a@mail.com";"2.2100"
"23.0";"b@mail.com";"0.7990"
```

The column STORE now has ".0"...

Is there a way to configure the function "to_csv" to output exactly (values) as shown in print? Thanks in advance.

```
"STORE";"EMAIL_CONTACT";"VALUE"
"10";"a@mail.com";"2.2100"
"23";"b@mail.com";"0.7990"
```

**Solved**: The problem was with the decimal option:

```
df.to_csv(file, sep=";", index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, decimal=",")

"STORE";"EMAIL_CONTACT";"VALUE"
"10";"a@mail.com";"2.2100"
"23";"b@mail.com";"0.7990"
```

Thanks everyone for the support!

Comment: Why do you need quotes?, and also can you check the type of STORE values? print df.STORE.dtype? try only df.to_csv(file, sep=";", index=False)

Comment: It means that `STORE` column dtype is probably float, try `df['STORE'] = df['STORE'].astype(int)` and the write out to csv

Comment: At MSSQL table, STORE is a DECIMAL(8, 0).

Comment: The quotes are optional. Not really necessary to have them and 
`df.STORE.dtype` is float64 What confuses me is that when I'm printing df all values are as expected but when exporting it "adds" x.0 to STORE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STORE is probably a float, check it out with

```
print df.STORE.dtype
```

if so, do:

```
df.STORE = df.STORE.astype(int)
```

then:

```
df.to_csv("Test.csv", sep=";", index=False)
```

output:

```
STORE;EMAIL_CONTACT;VALUE
1;a@mail.com;2.2100
2;b@mail.com;0.7990
```

EDIT:
For tabulation use:

```
df.to_csv("Test.csv", sep="\t", index=False)
```

this will output a csv with this format:

```
STORE    EMAIL_CONTACT    VALUE
1    a@mail.com    2.2100
2    b@mail.com    0.7990
```

Comment: `print(df.STORE.dtype)` returns float64. Is there a way to output exactly as is displayed? Because sql could be SELECT A, B FROM TABLE or SELECT X, Y, Z FROM TABLE.

Comment: you can use \t as a sep for tabulation, check the edit.

Comment: The tabulation will make a separation between values, but you can not have exactly a file exported with adjusted columns unless you do it manally, then it's not a csv.

Comment: Thank you for the reply YODA. My problem is not with the delimiter. Is trying to output to csv exactly (values, not the delimiter) as showed in the print(df). The variable SQL is "variable" that means I can't use df.STORE.astype(int) because it could not exist. For example, SQL could be SELECT STORE FROM ST but the in the next process it could be SELECT AMOUNT FROM DF. My objective is to be dynamic. What's strange is that when printing df everything is ok but when exporting it results in a different result.

Comment: I see,  but as far as I know psql.read_sql returns a pandas dataframe, so you need to have a full usage of dataframe and series options, unless you have an old version of pandas. what is your version of pandas?

Comment: The version of pandas is 0.16.2.

Comment: Sorry for all the trouble. When using decimal="," it all worked fine. A rookie mistake... `df.to_csv(file, sep=";", index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, decimal=",")`

Comment: @PauloG.P. I'm glad you found out.